# IE9 canvas scale issue. won't maintain aspect ratio to fit to container

Tags: css, canvas, html5-canvas

I can't seem to scale a canvas that's populated by an image within a fixed container in IE9. anyone know a work around? I recall reading some other thread about how IE treats a canvas as a block element

```
<style type="text/css">
#container { max-width: 25%; max-height: 25%; }
canvas { max-width: 90%; max-height: 90%; }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://l.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/121214/babydeer340.jpg';

img.onload = function () { 
    $('canvas').each(function () {
        var ctx = this.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    });
};​
</script>
<div id="container">
    <canvas id='fit-to-specified-width-height-with-aspect-ratio'></canvas>
</div>

<canvas id='normal'></canvas>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VAXrL/535/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too wish this behavior was consistent in all browsers but it looks like IE9 and a couple others treat canvas like a block level element and so you would need to style both width and height.

The canvas element will have to rely on hard pixels in its size since it is rasterized. One approach would be to calculate and set these pixels based on the original size of the image and a desired scale.

I forked your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cbosco/ttU5L/3/

```
var img = new Image();

var SCALE = 0.25;

img.onload = function () { 
    $('canvas').each(function () {
        var w = img.width;
        var h = img.height;
        w *= SCALE;
        h *= SCALE;        

        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        var ctx = this.getContext("2d");
        ctx.scale(SCALE, SCALE);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    });
};

// good idea to set src attribute AFTER the onload handler is attached             
img.src = 'http://l.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/121214/babydeer340.jpg';
​
```

Comment: A pure CSS approach would be to use CSS transforms, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/cbosco/rj4CW/1/ (IE-specific)

Comment: you sir are the man. they both work, and I could probably use that function to later resize the css of the canvas as well. thank you!